# Custom control dependency property not working

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, custom-controls

In my CustomControl I have the following dependency property:

```
public bool Favorite
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(FavoriteProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FavoriteProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Enabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty FavoriteProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Favorite", typeof(bool), typeof(FavoriteCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFavoriteChanged)));

private static void OnFavoriteChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FavoriteCustomControl control = (FavoriteCustomControl) dependencyObject;
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock) control.GetTemplateChild(HeartPartName);

    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        double opacity = ((bool)e.NewValue) ? 1 : 0.2;
        textBlock.Opacity = opacity;
    }
}
```

And when I declare in my window:

```
<custom:FavoriteCustomControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" Favorite="true"/>
```

it works in the designer view but not when I run the application. I debugged the max I could and I only catch one thing that I think it may be the problem:

`OnFavoriteChanged` callback runs the exacly amount of times that it should but `var textBlock` is always **null**. Well not always because in the designer mode I see that opacity changes and so `var textBlock` is not null.

I am really stuck and I don't know where to look for errors/bugs causing this.

**EDIT:**

Now I found that `OnFavoriteChanged` callback is called before `OnApplyTemplate()` and I think that's why `textBlock` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the standard WPF approach:

```
<TextBlock Opacity="{Binding Path=Favorite, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type custom:FavoriteCustomControl}}, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpacityConverter}}"/>
```

Note: you need to create class `BoolToOpacityConverter` and define it as a resource. Example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx).

Comment: I am not using WPF but .NET for Windows Store instead so `FindAncestor` is not recognized. But I tried that way using {TemplateBinding Opacity} where Opacity was a double instead of a boolean. It did not work

Comment: @letiagoalves anyway, you always can explicit call `OnFavoriteChanged` after `InitializeComponent` ;)